# Facebook Messenger: Cannot restrict address book access

Tags: ios, contacts, facebook

For security reasons I had to block address book access in iOS 10 entirely. WhatsApp for example doesn't see any address book entries and gives a warning. Any other app too. But the Facebook Messenger app behaves different. You can choose any contact from address book to start a new conversation. So how can I be sure, that contacts won't be uploaded to Facebook at all?

Comment: I'm not sure anyone except Facebook can answer this.  The only way to be sure is to uninstall Facebook and Messenger.  What kind of solution are you looking for?

Comment: The question is: Does that Facebook app get a different kind of iOS integration regarding restrictions? I could not find any clear statement from Facebook or Apple. And I'm sure, I'm not the only one looking for an answer.

Comment: No, they do not.  All apps have the same process of requesting access to contacts because all apps must call the same Apple API.  Apple is very restrictive regarding access to Contacts, Calendar, etc, especially if you're using iOS10 (you didn't mention the version you're using).  For Messenger to use your Contacts you have to explicitly give Facebook (any app) permission to do so.

Comment: Ok, I updated my question. I'm using iOS 10. When I first started that Messenger app, I expected the behaviour you mentioned. But it instantly gave me access to my contacts, regardless of those settings in the restrictions section of the iOS. That's what makes me wonder.

Comment: Is that the only Facebook app you have for that Apple ID across all devices?  Is it possible you granted Facebook access in the past?  I've never seen an app get around that permission request for a *non-jailbroken* device.

Comment: It's the only FB app. Well I just installed the Messenger app on a second device, where no critical contacts are on, but also with the same restriction setting. It seems the app won't sync any contacts with Facebook, but the contacts choser does work and it's a kind of "system contacts choser" with full access. Strange though!